Suggestion: separate tag for older IDAPython questions and some way to "renovate" these Q&As?
given there was an overhaul of IDAPython that also made the names more pythonic (snake-case) and rearranged where certain functionality went, but one can still find numerous questions referring to the old IDAPython, I was wondering two things:

shouldn't we have a separate tag for IDAPython? I was thinking along the lines of idapython-pre-7.x or similar (because if we called it idapython-old we'd run into the same issue if there is ever again any overhaul).
can't we "renovate" these Q&As in the sense that at least the new functions (including module name) and potentially a link to the documentation can be used?

Right now many of these Q&As are not really helpful because 1.) one has to figure out if it's new/old IDAPython and 2.) when faced with old IDAPython one has to look up the old/new name and practically start over with the answer ...
